Why are there two types of relative angular velocities?
When I was studying the relative motion of satellites I came across 2 formulas for relative angular velocity. One was for the relative angular velocity of one satellite about the other,
$$ω=\frac{|\vec v_1-\vec v_2|}{|\vec r_1-\vec r_2|}$$
while the other was the relative angular velocity of one with respect to the other with respect to the center of the planet they are orbiting,
$$\omega=|\omega_1-\omega_2|$$
I understand that the latter is a measure of how faster one is rotating about the center of the planet than the other, but what is the reason for the occurrence of 2 relative velocities? Is it because the angular velocity of any body depends on the velocity of the body about a point so the definition of angular velocity depends both on the frame (due to velocity) and point of reference (due to the nature of angular variables)?

The question would be clearer if you cite the formulae with some context about the angles / other parameters they contain.

I agree with @Amit, can you provide the equations?  Some equations used in orbital mechanics are for very specific circumstances.  If you're using one of them, a generic answer might lead you astray.

Formulae were added by the OP -- but I was a bit unsure how to transcribe the second one to MathJax. @Mayo - please review, essentially what you wrote won't make sense if $\vec{r}_i$ and $\vec{v}_i$ were vectors because division isn't really defined (in the original formula it seems you first divide the vector difference, then take an absolute value of the fraction...)

"Angular velocity" simply means the rate of change of an angle. What that angle is depends on which central point and which baseline it is being measured from. So an object can have many angular velocities defined in different ways.
So the angular velocity of one satellite about another will be the rate of change of the direction of one satellite as seen from the other, presumably taking some fixed direction in space as the baseline for measuring that angle. Whereas the relative angular velocity of the satellites as seen from the planet will be be the rate of change of the angle of one satellite as (hypothetically) seen from the centre of the planet but using the direction of the other satellite as a baseline. Alternatively, you could calculate the angular velocities of both satellites as seen from the planet and then subtract one from the other.

How does the measurement of an angle depend on the direction that is taken as the baseline? This makes no sense to me, how can angle depend on direction?

@Mayo An angle is a measure of the difference between one direction and another. If I say your angle from me is $10$ degrees, this does not fix your direction unless I specify a baseline.  If I say your angle is $10$ degrees East of North then I have fixed your direction.

Oh OK that's much more clear now, thanks.
